# Shoutcast media metainfo updates

Tags: java, media, shoutcast

Hi I have implemented the Shoutcast streaming protocol to get the Stream metainfo (as described somewhere on the web). I get the string with the song title and author, but what happens when during the stream, one song ends, another starts.. how do I recognize whether the song has ended and get the new metainfo?

How is this implemented in other players? They present the current song title immediately as it changes on the stream..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help: http://www.smackfu.com/stuff/programming/shoutcast.html

In short: when metadata is requested you will get metadata block after each N bytes of the stream (N is returned in the response header). The server will send the metadata block after connecting and on song change.

Comment: I couldn't understand your solution. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @efeyc Ask a specific question (possibly as a separate one).

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593361/how-to-get-informed-of-new-song-info-while-retrieving-metadata-from-shoutcast-str) is the new question.